# Change URL last component name and add extension to the renamed one

Tags: ios, swift3, nsstring, nsurl

I have the following `URL`

`file:///Users/ivancantarino/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CCE2FCA5-05F0-4BB7-9A25-CBC168398A62/data/Containers/Data/Application/E48179F9-84FB-4CB3-B993-1E33FCFB5083/Library/Caches/CloudKit/34af81edf8344be1cf473ef394e06ccc8e1bc8cf/Assets/AE86E028-E4E0-45D5-B5FE-BAE975D07F2A.0166f7df06d2562d8d53e70a3779a46de3769584c3`

I'm trying to rename the last part component of this url, but still having a url not only the filename.

I've managed to access the last part with the following code:

```
func extractAndBreakFilenameInComponents(fileURL: NSURL) {  
    let fileURLParts = fileURL.path!.components(separatedBy: "/")
    let fileName = fileURLParts.last
    print("filename:", fileName)
    // prints: AE86E028-E4E0-45D5-B5FE-BAE975D07F2A.0166f7df06d2562d8d53e70a3779a46de3769584c3
}
```

I want to change the `fileName` to something like `myFile.pdf` but keeping the `URL`

It is a simple URL rename, not creating a new one, just changing the existing one

What's the best approach on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do with this way

```
var url = URL.init(string: "http://www.example.com/test123")

url?.deleteLastPathComponent()
url?.appendPathComponent("file.pdf")


print(url)
```

> Output :http://www.example.com/file.pdf

Hope it helps to you

**EDIT**

You need to rename file use following code

1) Create Copy and update last component

```
var urlNew = URL.init(string: "http://www.example.com/test123")

urlNew?.deleteLastPathComponent()
urlNew?.appendPathComponent("file.pdf")



              do {
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: oldURL!, toPath: urlNew)
                } catch {

                }
```

Comment: will this change the file path itself? or just the pointer?

I mean, will the file itself change it's name and the pointer will now be with the file.pdf as you said?

Asking this because I can do the way you've said but then when accessing the file from the url it may not find it because the file name is still in the previous stage.

Comment: It will Change last test123 to file.pdf . that you need right ? and rest of will be untouched

Comment: exactly. I thought it will only create a new URL with a ghost filename that wouldn't properly exist on the device inner folder; but as you said it changes the real filename i'll give it a try and I'll feedback soon. Thank You ;)

Comment: Ok Good luck  ..:)

Comment: not as expected, probably because I've explained myself wrongly. maybe what I have to do is to change the filename at a specific URL-path

Comment: as you've said it creates a new url like I want to, but when I access that url-path physically the file didn't change its name, I might need to change the file name at a specific location first then retrieve its new url

Comment: I'll probably create a new question for this one, and set your as correct for what I've asked here, because your way works great to change the file name url

Comment: Well !! You have just added question about rename URL

Comment: @IvanCantarino I am updating answer accordingly

Comment: I know :) and it works the way you said, that's why I marked it as correct answer. But for my purpose (which I just noticed) I need to change the file name physically and the folder (renaming it) , then retrieve its url, which will come with the name already set

Comment: Perfect, perfect, perfect!
Sorry for explaining myself wrongly in the first place -- now it is perfect; renames the file and now I have it with the desired extension + newly updated url

Comment: Happy to help you :]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
let fileName = fileURLParts.last
    var newPath = ""
    for i in 0 ..< fileURLParts.count 
    {
        if i == (fileURLParts.count-1) {
            newPath.append(fileName)
        }else{
            newPath.append(fileURLParts[i])
        }

    }
```